# How do we get the whole string by pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm new to the C language and I'm getting aquanted with pointers. So, I don't get how we get the **WHOLE** string by pointer.
If the pointer contains the address of just the **first** character in the string, how does it return the whole string?

Let's say we have something like this `char *s = "Test";`

And because it's just an array of chars it lies somewhere in memory like this:

The string: T    e    s  t  \0

The addresses: 100 101 102 103 104

So, `*s` would hold `100` (the address of the first character `T`), if I get it right.

Then why when we do `printf(s);` do we get the whole string `Test` in our output?

Does it scan addresses until it meets `\0`, or does it do something else?

Comment: "Does it scan addresses until it meets \0 or what?" [Yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).

Comment: Even though it looks like not a very good question, it is showing the thought process I wish every C beginner followed...

Comment: Question worth a +1, I emphatically agree with Eugene.

Comment: Looks like you've already beaten a common misconception that beginners have. `char *` points to a single character, not a string.  The other characters of the string can then be found because we know that the characters in the string occupy consecutive memory locations.

Comment: @M.M I was just confused with printing the pointer. Fow now I think that it works something like this (correct if I'm wrong):
`char *s = "Test"; printf(s);`
What approximately happens inside printf:

`while(*s!= '\0') {`

 `printf("%c", *s); s++; `

`}`

Comment: Quite right, although that's closer to `puts`; since `printf` also has to check for `%` signs in the string

Comment: *"How do we get the whole string by pointer in C language?"* -- because it has that little `'\0'` at the end and string functions scan forward from the first character until they find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do we get the whole string by pointer

Yes, OP does well understand in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876766/how-do-we-get-the-whole-string-by-pointer-in-c-language/53877411#comment94601892_53876766) that to print the *string* contents, the output starts at `s[0]` and continues until `s[i]` is zero.  The last element of the *string*, the *null character* is not printed.

---

Note: `printf(s)` is *bad* code as `printf()` expects the first argument to not only be a pointer to a *string*, but will interpret as a *format*.  If a `'%'` occurs, following characters will be interpreted as a specifier [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876766/how-do-we-get-the-whole-string-by-pointer-in-c-language/53877411#comment94602206_53876766). Instead:

```
printf("%s", s);
// or
fputs(s, stdout);
```

---

- Impact

Functions like `strlen(), strcpy(), strcat()` also spend a fair amount of time walking down the length of a *string* to determine its length.  For long *strings*, this can take considerable time.

This tedious running the length of the string can have severe impacts. Consider `s` points to a string of length `n`.

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) {
  s[i] = 'x';
}
```

versus

```
for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
  s[i] = 'x';
}
```

The first code snippet compilation may not see that the length of the string does not change (as the string is changed) per iteration and then call `strlen(n)` `n` times, each call taking `n` operations or total `O(n*n)`  time.  The 2nd code will only take order of `n` operations O(n) time.

Efficient C code recognizes this and avoids repeated length calculations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way just to go through the whole string until zero is reached:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while(*str++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

or

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *start = str;
    while(*str++);
    return str - start;
}
```

---

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *saveddest = dest;

    while(*src)
    {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return saveddest;
}

void puts(const char *s)
{
    char c;
    while((c = *s++))
        putc(c);
}
```

Comment: thanks.
What's under the hood of this:`char *s = "Test";
   printf(s);`

Does it work something like this?:

  `while(*s!= '\0') {
    printf("%c", *s);
    s++;
  }`

Comment: Yes it does not use printf but it has a function which outputs every char from the string

Comment: 2nd `strlen()` is off by one.  Suggest `while(*str++);` --> `while(*str) str++;`

Comment: Note: standard `puts()` lastly prints a `'\n'` (and returns an `int`), unlike this  `puts()`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a string is array of characters and the name of the array corresponds to the pointer referencing the address of the first element.

so when you do printf("%s",s) this means that you are passing the pointer of the very first element of the char array to the printf function.

The printf function would traverse through the array starting from the address passed until it finds '\0'

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char *s= "abcdef ghij";
  char *s2;
  s2 = &s[3];
  printf("%s",s2);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice how I passed the pointer referencing the 4 element of the array to the  printf function. And here is the output.

Output:

> def ghij